# image wont render, path is base on the storage path

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, laravel, laravel-5

I have this function on my controller

```
public function get_images(Request $request){
    $images = inventory_images::where('item_id',$request->id)->get();
    $path = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();

    return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'images' => $images, 'id' => $request->id, 'path' => $path ]);
}
```

so the '$path' contains the storage path, my images stored on the 'storage' folder and the '$images' contains the file name and then in my front end side (rendering the image)

```
$.each(e.images,function(index,value){
    $("#notification_dialog #gallery-items-container").append('<a href="'+e.path+value.image_name+'"> <figure> <img src="'+e.path+value.image_name+'"> </figure></a>');
});
```

in the image 'src' I have this path

> C:\wamp\www\Clinic and Inventory
>   System\storage\app\public\items_gallery\10014589_974440645904700_5867266076580720168_n.jpg

In the console, I have this error

> :1 Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/wamp/www/Clinic%20and%20Inventory%20System/storage/app/public/items_gallery/10014589_974440645904700_5867266076580720168_n.jpg

The image did not render and If I paste the path unto the browser, I can see the image so it means that the path was correct and just the image is not rendering, any ideas, help please?

Answer (score -1):

Put a data attribute on the tag holding the image:

```
data-image_path="{{ asset('uploads/*name of model this is being associated with/original/') }}"
```

Where **asset** points to your project's public directory.

Then retrieve the image name from the controller and append it to that path.

Comment: as I said, images is located to the storage folder, not on the public folder.

Comment: You have "/app/public/items_gallery/" in your storage folder?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution somewhere,

```
Route::get('/images/{image}', function($image = null)

{
    $path = storage_path().'/app/public/items_gallery/' . $image;
    if (file_exists($path)) { 
        return Response::download($path);
    }
});
```

and its okay now.